# How to work Parent layout click to all child layouts?

Tags: android, onclick

In my application, I have a bottom menu So I have implemented the bottom layout for all the screens. I have one red button for the menu visible and gone, This functionality is working fine. But here my one more requirement is when clicking on the screen(outside the menu) a bottom menu will disappear. In my screens so many child layouts are available. here my parent layout is Coordinator layout. So I have created to id to Coordinator layout and Implemented OnClick listener for this one. So In OnClick, I will disappear the menu.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:id="@+id/coord_layout"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/fgtrellayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/topBanner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorScreenBG"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <include
            android:id="@+id/action_bar"
            layout="@layout/custom_action_bar">
        </include>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/topBanner"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:background="@color/colorScreenBG"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/instctsText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
            android:text="@string/forgotPasswordAlert"
            android:textColor="#040101"
            android:textSize="@dimen/normal_font_size" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center">
            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                style="@style/MyTextInputLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:errorEnabled="false">
                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/fgtActNoVal"
                    style="@style/MyTextInputEditText"
                    android:layout_width="200dip"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/acctNo_UserId"
                    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:maxLength="30"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/normal_font_size" />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                style="@style/MyTextInputLayout"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:errorEnabled="false">
                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/fgtTelVal"
                    style="@style/MyTextInputEditText"
                    android:layout_width="200dip"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/tel_No"
                    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:maxLength="4"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/normal_font_size" />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
            <TextView
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:id="@+id/dgtsLmt"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/lastFourDigits"
                android:textColor="#ff0000"
                android:textSize="@dimen/tenfont" />
            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/mailcheckBox"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
                android:text="@string/emailMyPassword"
                android:textColor="#040101"
                android:textSize="@dimen/normalLayout"
                android:visibility="invisible" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/btnsLayot"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp">
            <android.support.design.button.MaterialButton
                style="@style/MyButton"
                android:id="@+id/fgtClose"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/back"
                android:textAllCaps="false"/>
            <android.support.design.button.MaterialButton
                style="@style/MyButton"
                android:id="@+id/fgtReset"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:text="@string/reset"
                android:textAllCaps="false"/>
            <android.support.design.button.MaterialButton
                style="@style/MyButton"
                android:id="@+id/fgtSubmit"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:text="@string/submit"
                android:textAllCaps="false" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
<include layout="@layout/bottom_sheet_login"
    android:visibility="visible" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>``
```

So in the above xml, Coordinator layout on click is working fine. But if the layout having listview or webview then parent layout on click is not working

This is the xml file

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/coord_layout"
    android:background="@color/colorScreenBG"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"> 
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/total_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">    
        <include
            android:id="@+id/topBanner"
            layout="@layout/custom_action_bar"></include> 
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/NoticeLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">    
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/locations1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="50dip"
                android:text="@string/noInfoExists"
                android:textColor="#C00000"
                android:textSize="@dimen/normalHeadings" />    
            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/locations"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                android:background="#00000000"
                android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
                android:textColor="#040101" />    
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>    
    <include
        layout="@layout/bottom_sheet_login"
        android:visibility="visible" />    
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

In my application, so many screens are there. When clicking on the screen(Outside the menu) the menu will disappear. So how to work parent layout on click for all the child views.

Check the bellow image

[image]

So please help with this.

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 0):

First, add those to your root view for touchable area.

```
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
```

After that, you can use onFocusChanged listener to handle your views' behaviour.